# How to return specific assaing value from model when foreign key null Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, database-migration

when a foreign key value is null I want to return a specific value from the model because when I delete the primary key id row and set a null value on the foreign key shows error. how to can I do it please anybody help me?

Here Is My Country Migration Table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 60)->nullable();
            $table->string('country_code', 60)->nullable();
            $table->string('capital', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('region', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('currency_code', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('currency_name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('currency_symbol', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('language_code', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('language_name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('flag')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('flag')->references('id')->on('media_files')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('dialling_code', 10)->nullable();
            $table->integer('status')->default(0)->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Here Is My City migration Table:

```
Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('zipcode')->nullable();
            $table->string('order')->default(null)->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('country_id')->nullable()->constrained("countries")->cascadeOnUpdate()->nullOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

City Model:

```
class City extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function country(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class,'country_id');
    }
}
```

Frontend Blade:

```
<tbody>
                    @foreach($CityList as $City)
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]"></td>
                        <td>{{$City->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{$City->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{$City->zipcode }}</td>
                        <td>{{$City->country->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{$City->country->countrycode }}</td>
                        <td>{{$City->order }}</td>
                        <td>{{$City->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="{{ route('dashboard.city.edit',$City->id) }}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size: 17px;"></i></a>
                          <button href="{{ route('dashboard.city.delete',$City->id) }}" type="button" value="{{ $City->id }}" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                          </button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

[image: enter code here]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to return the default value instead of a real country?

Comment: yes, like when the foreign key is null show "No country found" but I don't want to write this way {{$City->country ? $City->country->name : 'No country found'}}

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest a few ways to solve this

First: Make a default value for the relation, like here

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(...)->withDefault(['name' => 'No country']);
}
```

Second: Make a mutation in City model to find the name of the country

```
protected function countryName(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => $this->country-> name ?? 'Not country',
    );
}
```

> Notes: This way works only for `laravel 9.x +`, for older versions
> please read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) article

Answer (score 1):

You can do this: `<td>{{$City->country ? $City->country->name : 'No country found'}}</td>`

And make sure you are including `countries` when fetching `cities`.

Comment: thanks for your solution, but I want to set the default value from the model. i don't want to check each time from blade